# Winsock send() issue with single byte transmissions

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I'm experiencing a frustrating behaviour of windows sockets that I cant find any info on, so I thought I'd try here.

My problem is as follows:

I have a C++ application that serves as a device driver, communicating with a serial device connected
through a serial to TCP/IP converter.
The serial protocol requires a lot of single byte messages to be communicated between the device and
my software. I noticed that these small messages are only sent about 3 times after startup, after which they are no longer actually transmitted (checked with wireshark). All the while, the send() method keeps returning > 0, indicating that the message has been copied to it's send buffer.
I'm using blocking sockets.

I discovered this issue because this particular driver eventually has to drop it's connection when the send buffer is completely filled (select() fails due to this after about 5 hours, but it happens much sooner when I reduce SO_SNDBUF size).

I checked, and noticed that when I call send with messages of 2 bytes or larger, transmission never fails.

Any input would be very much appreciated, I am out of ideas how to fix this.

Comment: After a further bout of testing I have the following to add: Using an identical serial tp IP converter with a loopback connector installed on the serial line I tested the problem once more.

With this setup, no problems are occuring, even while sending 1-byte messages. A big difference is what I am seeing in my wireshark trace. My actual test system, with 3rd party device on serial, shows a lot of zero-window-probe messages being sent to the port converter. The loopback configuration does not show any such flags being used.

Comment: The first byte I send always ends up in those zero-window-probe messages. When I send more than 1 byte, a second package is sent containing the rest of the payload. 
When that second message is sent, communication stays alive. When I only send 1 byte messages, and only zero window probe messages are detected by wireshark, communication grinds to a halt very quickly.

If only I knew why the zero window probes are being sent, I dont recall any 0-window size being reported by the port converter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rare case when you should set TCP_NODELAY so that the sends are written individually, not coalesced. But I think you have another problem as well. Are you sure you're *reading* everything that's being sent back? And acting on it properly? It sounds like an application protocol problem to me.

Comment: I already experimented with both TCP_NODELAY as well as SO_SNDBUF set to 0 with non-blocking ports. Made no difference to the behaviour when sending. I might add that the send call causes a hangup after the first few calls when using non-blocking ports with SO_SNDBUF set to 0.

Comment: Of course it does. I don't see the point of zeroing SO_SNDBUF, but that is exactly how I would expect it to behave. It sounds to me like the device isn't even reading from the connection.

Comment: No error, no return, just freezes.
As far as reading is concerned: all received data is read from the socket periodically (my code is called cyclically every 100ms). 
My experimenting so far only points out that repetitive 1-byte send messages cause something to go amiss, but the send call keeps returning OK and adding to the buffer, which is never sent out on the wire. I tried interspersing longer messages for test purposes every once so often, but it still fails as long as there are multiple consecutive 1-byte messages preceding it.

Comment: The idea behind zeroing SO_SNDBUF was to try to avoid having the socket buffering my messages.. IF the other side is not reading (it is a VLINX serial port converter we use often), then why are longer messages not causing problems?